# jsx файл не видит разметку

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, xml, jsx

[image: Вот так выглядит файл]При сборке проекта возникла проблема, не дает в файле jsx разметку сделать. Не знаю, как решить, гуглила, но без особого результата.

Пробовала отключать eslint, думала, в нем проблема, но не помогло. Поиск решений в интернете тоже не помог. А компоненты использовать нужно. Скриншоты прикрепляю
[image: Список ошибок]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: Вы используете фигурные скобки в `return`, нужно круглые `return (<div>...</div>)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно заменить литералы {} на (), т.е.:

```
function Card() {
  return (<div></div>);
};
```

FYI

https://ru.reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#jsx-is-an-expression-too

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/return

Comment: Спасибо! Да, спустя несколько часов исправила ситуацию. Обидно было обнаружить проблему в собственной невнимательности ))